# python using urllib2 and urllib get request issue

Tags: python, api, get, urllib, urllib2

when i use curl get request success,but using python call get request failed, anyone can help!

```
shell script:
curl -X GET -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$token'' -d '[ { "id":"535985", "language":"EN", "Detailes":{"LibraryId":"KF_2gl9xZYKX7TJi66" }, "KeyID":"SF_cY1tKhYiocNluBB" } ]' 'https://XXXX.com'
```

get request success.

```
python Script:
data ={ "id":"535985", "language":"EN", "Detailes":{"LibraryId":"KF_2gl9xZYKX7TJi66" }, "KeyID":"SF_cY1tKhYiocNluBB" }
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (token)}
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
DataForGet=urllib.urlencode(data)
NewUrl= apilink + "?" + DataForGet
request = urllib2.Request(NewUrl, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=300)
message = response.read()
```

the return message 
TypeError: unhashable type

anyone know how to use get request by  urllib2 and  urllib model. Many thanks!

Comment: Why not use [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: coz the server python version is 2.7 and we have no access to pip install requests model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found we can define this mothod to call api get data

```
class RequestMethod(urllib2.Request,object):
    def __init__(self, url, method=None,data=None, headers={},origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False):
        self.method = method
        super(RequestMethod,self).__init__(url, data=data,headers=headers,origin_req_host=origin_req_host,unverifiable=unverifiable)
    def get_method(self):
        if self.method != None:
            return self.method
        else:
            return super(RequestMethod,self).get_method()
    def set_method(self,method):
        self.method = method
    def setMethodRequest(url,method):
        return RequestMethod(url,method=method)
```